# Comparación con el operador lógico and (&&) entre un dato tipo string y uno parseado con parseInt: ¿es posible en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, operador, comparaciones

En este código la idea inicial era agregar un solo if para las dos variables, es decir, plantearlo con el operador lógico &&... pero en ese caso la variable "tipoArroz" al ser un string y la "variableCantidad" al ser un dato parseado, no se pueden poner juntas y que el condicional if lo tome como válido. En otras palabras, cuando se probó el hacer eso, en vez de saltar el alert "no se ingresaron datos", la función seguía ejecutándose y saltaba el alert de la función pero arrojando NaN.

¿Cómo se pudieran juntar en un solo condicional if a esas dos variables declaradas con let, con el operador lógico &&, si uno es un string y el otro un dato parseado con parseInt? ¿habría que parsear luego o incluso no parsear?

Así se probó esta porción del código con un solo condicional if y no funcionó:

```
if (tipoArroz && variableCantidad == "") {
      alert("No se ingresaron datos")
      continue
}
```

Por lo tanto tuvo que dividirse en dos condicionales, así:

```
//VARIABLES Y CONSTANTES

let tipoArroz = prompt(“Ingrese tipo de arroz que comera”)

console.log(tipoArroz);

//CONDICIONAL #1

if (tipoArroz == “”) {

alert(“No se ingresaron datos”)

continue

}

let variableCantidad = parseInt(prompt(“Ingrese cantidad de personas que comeran”));

//CONDICIONAL #2

if (variableCantidad == “”) {

alert(“No se ingresaron datos”);

continue

}
```

¿De qué manera se podría mejora u optimizar esto? ¿Es correcto el planteamiento con un solo if para mejorarlo o debería dejarse así como está?

Comment: Entre hacer menos código y darle mejor retroalimentación al usuario deberías preferir lo segundo. "No se ingresaron datos" ¿Cuáles datos? ¿Alguno en particular?.

Comment: Los datos serían: en el primer condicional sería el tipo de arroz que comerá (string) y en el segundo condicional la cantidad de personas (parsear a número entero). El código habla por sí mismo... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si lo he entendido bien porque en realidad tu la consulta la puedes hacer sobre el mismo if con cada variable por separado. Te dejo aquí un ejemplo en el que compruebo si el tipoArroz es vacío y si la variableCantidad es 0:

```js
var tipoArroz="";
var variableCantidad=0;

if (tipoArroz=="" && variableCantidad == 0) {
      alert("No se ingresaron datos");      
}
```

Si lo que quieres comprobar es si se cumple una de las 2 condiciones, entonces tienes que utilizar el or:

```js
var tipoArroz="";
    var variableCantidad=0;

    if (tipoArroz=="" || variableCantidad == 0) {
          alert("No se ingresaron datos");      
    }
```

Un saludo!